# Jenkins cannot execute webpack from ant script

Tags: jenkins, npm, ant, webpack

I am trying to execute an `Ant` script through jenkins but it fails when it attempts to use `webpack`...

The ant script's execution task is the following:

```
<exec executable="webpack.cmd" failonerror="true">
    <env key="PROD_ENV" value="true"/>
</exec>
```

where `webpack.cmd` has been installed as a global `npm` module. The module directory has been included in the `Path` variable and I have even made sure that Jenkins is actually able to see it by doing a trial run inside a `Execute windows batch command` build step. However when it attempts to execute it via Ant it fails. Could it be a problem with the Ant plugin and its version?

The error i'm getting is the following:

> Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "webpack.cmd": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 0):

`webpack.cmd` needs to run in a command shell. Try...

```
<exec executable="cmd" failonerror="true">
    <env key="PROD_ENV" value="true"/>
    <arg value="/c"/>
    <arg value="webpack.cmd"/>
</exec>
```

You may need to provide the full absolute path to `webpack.cmd` so `cmd.exe` can find it.

Comment: @Konstantine Do you still receive the `CreateProcess error=2` error? If so, what does it say?

Comment: It says the same thing as in the question